# How to specify WHERE in a JOIN statement?

Tags: php, mysql, join

This is my first attempt at a JOIN MySQL statement...

I have 2 tables..`games` and `games_ratings`

both tables have an id column. the id represents the id of the game. and i only want to get the average of the ints in the rating column where the id in games_ratings is equal to the id from the games table.

`SELECT a.id, a.name, AVG(b.rating) AS average FROM games a LEFT JOIN games_ratings b GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT 50;`

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, AVG(b.rating) AS average 
    FROM games a 
    LEFT JOIN games_ratings b
    ON a.id = b.id # <-- You need this line I believe 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT 50;
```

**Edit:** This is a bit hard without your complete schema, but you can try something like this.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, AVG(b.rating) AS average, COUNT( b.id) as votes
    FROM games a 
    LEFT JOIN games_ratings b
    ON a.id = b.id 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY votes DESC, average DESC LIMIT 50; # <-- You may need to modify this line
```

Comment: that did it! you rock. thanks! It's not letting me mark your answer as correct....for 11 minutes lol so ill mark it right eventually

Comment: 1 thing i just noticed....would you know how to make that return how many votes it has. then have it order it by average...but the more votes the higher it is? So I dont have a game with 1 5 star vote appearing higher than a 4.5 star rating with 800 votes

Comment: You can try the edit I just posted, however it may not work 100%. You will probably need to modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the WHERE clause he asked for:

> where the id in games_ratings is equal to the id from the games table

```
> SELECT a.id, a.name, AVG(b.rating) AS average 
>     FROM games a 
>     LEFT JOIN games_ratings b
>     ON a.id = b.id # <-- You need this line I believe
>     **WHERE a.id = b.id**  
>     GROUP BY a.id 
>     ORDER BY average DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, that `WHERE` clause won't do anything because it won't change the results at all. Only rows from both tables with equal IDs will be returned because of the `JOIN`, adding that `WHERE` clause is like adding `WHERE 1 = 1`, pointless.

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it, since it is a `LEFT JOIN`, there may be no matching `b.id` for `a.id`, meaning your `WHERE` clause will remove those rows from the result set. However, if this were the desired result, then the `LEFT JOIN` should become a `JOIN`, eliminating the need for this `WHERE` clause.

Comment: If he/she had questioned the WHERE differently (ie: where the id = 6) you would have needed it

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If the OP had asked a different question, I would have needed a different answer.